# Flutter: Most efficient way to pass properties (width of a section) to widgets

Tags: flutter

##### Preamble

Although this question is strictly about passing the width of a component down a widget tree, it's kind of also touching on what the best practices of passing data around a widget tree is.

## Problem

I have a two section desktop app that I'm building using Flutter.

- The left hand pane is a selection of items that can be clicked
- The right pane presents more information about the currently selected item

The app is responsive, with the right hand pane moving widgets around a bit, and some sections being a percentage of the available width. Now I'm relatively new to flutter, so I wanted to know what the best / most efficient way to pass the width of the right hand pane down the Widget tree is:

### Pass width property down the widget tree

The containing Widget for the right hand pane has a `LayoutBuilder` which tells me the current width. For a few of its children, I've passed the `width` of the section down. Coming from a React background, I know that this gets tedious and is somewhat frowned upon.

### Use multiple LayoutBuilder widgets

I don't know whether this is a good idea nor whether it is efficient. But could I just a `LayoutBuilder` everywhere I need to know the width of the current section? Is this actually even inefficient at all?

### Use a provider

I use `Riverpod` for my state management. In theory, I could just have a listener under my top-level `LayoutBuilder` which then the components that need to know the width can listen to. This however feels like it could cause performance issues too.

### Something else

Once again, I'm relatively new to flutter, so there might be something so obvious that I've missed

Any advice / suggestions / best practises welcome

Comment: Check out this summary by Pixeltoast on the fundamentals of Flutter layout including MediaQuery: https://notes.tst.sh/flutter/media-query/